# Changing the source of an include in html, using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, pug

Currently I'm including one svg as external pug file, in my main pug file.
Since I have multiple vectors (different files), I was wondering if there is an option to change the source of the include in JavaScript.

Here is my pug structure

```
.services_description
    figure
        include tools/jade_includes/components/svgs/vision_1
```

Comment: You can send JSON data to PUG `{"url": "tools/jade_includes/components/svgs/vision_1"}`. See http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no, you can't dynamically change includes at runtime".

However, there is a workaround.  SVG files can be loaded with an `img` tag so pass the sc attribute into the template.  [Here's an article](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) that talks about loading svg files.

Route (node/express):

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('page', { "svgLink" : "/path-to/vision_1.svg"} );
});
```

Template (pug):

```
.services_description
    figure
        img(src= svgLink)
```

You could also use a [conditional](https://pugjs.org/language/conditionals.html) to solve this, but note that all of your svg's will be cached in the pug engine and this could consume a lot of memory on your server.  The positive is that your svg files will be rendered super-quick.

```
.services_description
    figure
      if flag === 'vision_1'
        include tools/jade_includes/components/svgs/vision_1
      else if flag === 'vision_2'
        include tools/jade_includes/components/svgs/vision_2
      else if flag === 'vision_3'
        include tools/jade_includes/components/svgs/vision_3
```